# What should I do to upgrade my current 32 bit Python to 64 bit - do I need additional package or to uninstall current?

Tags: installation, python, 64-bit, 32-bit

Getting involved with gradually more complex assignments in Python, I wanted to install spacy via a pip install command, but realised (looking into a # of error reports) that spacy (used in text mining) does no longer support Python 32 bit version. I am running that now, leaving me with the following questions to the community:

1. Python.org shows a list of packages on download page of web (have W10 installed)
2. Is an additional package download to support 64 bit ops sufficient or do I need to reinstall Python from the beginning?
3. If yes to aforementioned question, does that harm all other code bodies I did, e.g. in my PyCharm IDE?

I'd very much appreciate some input here. I suspect--when attempting to download tensorflow, nltk.corpora, etc--that the above bit issue also is the cause of failure here

Comment: this might be of some help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522943/is-it-possible-to-upgrade-a-portable-python-32-bit-install-to-a-64-bit-install)

Comment: Thx, unfortunately it did not make any diffence, thanks anyway..;o)

Comment: Were u able to find out any solution for this?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-have-32-and-64-bit-Python-installed-at-once-Will-there-be-any-issues-I-accidentally-installed-32-bit-a-while-ago-and-I-dont-know-how-to-upgrade-it-without-messing-anything-up/answer/Renie-Ananthakumar-1